# Подскажите ка работает Model.IsValid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня код выводит сообщение "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует".
Как `Model.IsValid` проверяет есть ли в базе пользователь с таким логином.

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = null;
        using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
        {
            user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Name);
        }
        if(user == null)
        {
            using (UserContext db  = new UserContext())
            {
                db.Users.Add(new User {Email = model.Name, Password = model.Password, Age = model.Age });
                db.SaveChanges();
                user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == model.Name && u.Password == model.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            //ecli polzovatel' udachno dabavlen  v bd 
            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Name, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Pol'zovatel' s takim loginom uzhe sushestvuet");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Так у тебя прописаны все проверки. В чем вопрос?

Comment: в блоке else добавлеятся элемент в список, а в самом методе IsValid проверяется количество на ноль [тут подробнее](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/ModelBinding/ModelStateDictionary.cs#L37-L41)

Comment: Никак `Model.IsValid` этого не проверяет. Проверка написана дальше обращением к БД в коде: `user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Name);`.

Comment: почитайте тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/881351/7198805

Answer (score 1):

На модель накладываются определенные условия, некоторые из них сложные и некоторые из них простые. Фреймворк может самостоятельно проверять некоторые простые условия, которые накладываются на модель данных. К таким условиям могут относится: длинна строки `MaxLength`, `MinLength`, `StringLength`; диапазон `Range`; регулярное выражение `RegularExpression`; обязательность `Required`. К примеру это может выглядеть так:

```
class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(7)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Range(typeof(DateTime),"1-Jan-1910","1-Jan-2017")]
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
}
```

Дальше, когда пользователь отправляет данные на сервер, модель проверяется по этим критериям фреймворком и результат проверки доступен в классе [`ModelState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx). В частности метод `IsValid` показывает, прошли ли все проверки успешно. Вот и все, ни в какую базу он не лезет.

При этом `ModelState` является своего рода словарем, в котором содержатся ошибки и их описания. При желании можно в коде сделать проверку более сложного характера и добавить в случае чего ошибку в этот словарь. Обратите внимание на код в вашем исходнике, который это и делает - добавляет свою собственную ошибку принудительно:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Pol'zovatel' s takim loginom uzhe sushestvuet");
```

Ну в остальном, если знаете `EntityFramefork` и `Linq for EntityFramefork`, то никаких проблем быть не должно с пониманием работы кода. Лезем сами в базу, проверяем параметры пользователя и выводим результат.

```
...
user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Name);
...
if(user == null)
{
    using (UserContext db  = new UserContext())
    {
         //добавляем пользователя
         db.Users.Add(new User {Email = model.Name, Password = model.Password, Age = model.Age });
         db.SaveChanges();
         user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == model.Name && u.Password == model.Password).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
else
{
    //Пользователь есть, добавляем свою собственную ошибку в список
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Pol'zovatel' s takim loginom uzhe sushestvuet");
}
```

Ну и дальше View смотрит ошибки и выводит их.

P.S. данный код у Вас никогда не выполнится

```
if(user == null)
{
    if (user != null) //он уже и так null согласно проверки выше, всегда false !!!
    {
         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Name, true);
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```